# Flash content on Chrome correctly asks me to enable it but then asks me to right click to run it which does nothing

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, flash, chromium, wayland

I recently tried to install Flash for Chromium and Firefox but now no flash content works, not even Chrome which has its own Flash. My issue with Flash content in Firefox is that it crashes right after any input.

I used `sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer` but nothing changed.

Comment: `flashplugin-installer` doesn't help for Chromium, and Chrome doesn't need a separate Flash package at all. Please see https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html

Comment: @gunnar-hjalmarsson After installing the PPAPI, Flash on Chrome got messed up. That guide doesn't say how to uninstall it so I used the result from a Google Search which actually led me back to AskUbuntu

Comment: Chrome shouldn't be affected by the presence of a Flash package at all; it includes a PPAPI copy by itself. Did you install the PPAPI in some other way than through the `adobe-flashplugin` package?

Comment: I didn't. I wasn't expecting Chrome's Flash to break either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flash with Chromium or Google Chrome broken on Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141108/flash-with-chromium-or-google-chrome-broken-on-ubuntu-19-04)

Comment: That was posted after mine though. I'm confused.

Comment: True. But the other question includes better answers and explanations. I tried to be practical.

Comment: " I tried to be practical." :( This just makes me feel sad.

Comment: That was really not my intention. Is there any part of the issue you reported which hasn't been explained or solved?

Answer (score 0):

Went back to X from Wayland and BAM! Firefox is fixed. **Unfortunately Chrome and Chromium aren't fixed.**