# How to solve flash player problem in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: apt, google-chrome, flash, adobe

Last week I updated from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10 to 19.04 in two steps. After completing, I found that Adobe Flash Player does no longer work. Neither in Firefox nor Chrome.

I tried to solve it by re-installing pepperflashplugin, which I only later found out to be for Firefox, not for Chrome. Afterwards I tried to install Adobe Flash via Canonical partners, but I seem to have the latest version of Flash Player installed.

Then I tried to purge Chrome and re-install.

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

It seemed to be removed by that, but once I reinstalled, it was back exactly the way T left it. Didn't feel like a clean install anyway.

When I check isflashinstalled.com it also says it is installed. But when I encounter a website that needs Flash Player that used to work, I get the usual, right click to run Adobe Flash Player but nothing happens when I choose run plugin. When I choose to hide this plugin, it kinda seems to try to work but there is never any videos appearing.

I looked through all 5 answers of "How to install Flash player on Ubuntu?". Unfortunately, none of the possible answers were viable or functional. I did try to install pepper flash also, but no benefit there, can this attempt to install be as issue? and should I uninstall pepper flash?

Anyway, although the other topic seems relevant on first glance. none of the solutions seem to work for me.

This evening I tried to use the "Chromium Flash Player Not Working on Ubuntu 19.04" solution using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove chromium-browser   
sudo apt-get --purge remove google-chrome-stable   
sudo apt-get --purge remove pepperflashplugin-nonfree   
sudo apt-get --purge remove browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

Downloaded chrome from [Ofiicial Site](https://www.google.com/chrome/) and installed it via the GUI. Afterwards I tried if the embedded chrome flashplayer would function again, which it didn't.

Afterwards I ran:

```
sudo apt update  i
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

After checking canonical partners were still checked. Afterwards I tried again, but to no avail. After downloading i did get a few error messages. So this solution didn't seem to work.

Is there anyone who has the same issue with chrome (not chromium) as the 
complaints are exactly the same. so it does seem related and I assume I did some thing wrong or missed an essential step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Flash player on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341428/how-to-install-flash-player-on-ubuntu)

Comment: There is a Chromium issue, which may affect Chrome too. (See duplicate question.) Firefox ought to work, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chromium Flash Player Not Working on Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141108/chromium-flash-player-not-working-on-ubuntu-19-04)

Comment: unfortunately fire neither firefox nor chrome works.

Comment: it is getting a bit late here, but i will look into this "Chromium Flash Player Not Working on Ubuntu 19.04" issue tomorrow. this seems relevant to me.

Comment: unfortunately neither solution options seemed to work, also.. firefox doesnt work either.

Comment: @MatthieuKintsvan: The solution in that answer was to install a version of Chromium (not Chrome) which has not yet been released in Ubuntu 19.04. That's possible since it has been released in the development version of Ubuntu. As regards Chrome, I just tried (version 74.0.3729.157-1) and the bug seems to not have been fixed there. As regards Firefox I have a question: Is FF installed via a .deb package or as a snap? Flash only works with the .deb package without tweaks.

Comment: the version as installed after the uogrades. did not yet remove firefox. i will give chromium a go...

Comment: @MatthieuKintsvan: Something is a bit strange. The Chromium version I'm successfully using on 19.04 is 74.0.3729.131-0ubuntu1. The Chrome version is newer, and it still does not work properly. Did the bug resurrect?

Comment: @MatthieuKintsvan: You didn't really answer my FF question, btw. You can check by running the command `which firefox`

Comment: i just checked my version of chrome: Version 74.0.3729.157 (Official Build) (64-bit). what i meant is that i did not personally installed firefox, it was preinstalled so i assume is is a .deb. but can't be sure about that. the reply of "which firefox" was : /usr/bin/firefox. but i am not sure how informative that is.

Comment: well i indeed tried chromium.. and that works. so it seems the bug is just still there in chrome. not in chromium

Comment: Good that you made Chromium work. `/usr/bin/firefox` means that you have the .deb package, so together with `adobe-flashplugin` Flash should really work with Firefox too.

Comment: I wrote an answer to the other question which hopefully clears up a couple of questions: https://askubuntu.com/a/1144166